# Code to send emails from a list of email addresses, with a 1-hour delay after every 20 sends

Tags: python, loops

I have a list of email addresses I want my python code to iterate through. Thing is, I want the code to go through 20 of them, then wait an hour and then continue onto the next 20 until the loop goes through the entire list of xy addresses.

Im pasting my current code below, could you please help me out?

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import time

subject = ""
sender = ""
password = ""

with open('message.html', 'r', encoding="utf8") as file:
    html = file.read().replace('\n', '')

with open('message.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as file:
    text = file.read().replace('\n', '')

counter = 0
maxCount = 0
with open('list.txt') as z:
    for i in z:
        maxCount+=1


def send_email(subject, html, sender, recipients, password):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)

    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = recipients
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp_server:
       smtp_server.login(sender, password)
       smtp_server.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
       smtp_server.quit()
    print("MAIL: Sent")

with open('list.txt') as list:
    for address in list:
        recipients = address
        counter+=1
        send_email(subject, html, sender, recipients, password)
        print("Address: ", recipients)
        print("Count:", counter, "/",maxCount, " \n")
```

As I have said below, I am attempting to run the code through first 15 addresses of an xy amount, then wait for an hour and then continue onto the next 15 addresses and so on.

```
with open('zoznam.txt') as zoznam:
    for adresa in zoznam:
        if counter < 2:
            recipients = adresa
            counter+=1
            send_email(subject, html, sender, recipients, password)
            print("Adresa: ", recipients)
            print("Poradie:", counter, "/",maxCount, " \n")
        else:
            print("Čakám 5 sekúnd")
            time.sleep(5)
            continue
```

Doing this goes through the first 2 email addresses, then waits and continues sending an email to previously used email address, ignoring the next ones.

Answer (score -1):

Create a counter and increment it by 1 after sending each email. Once it reaches 15, trigger the 1-hour delay and set the counter to zero. Repeat the same once again till no more emails are left.

Comment: Yes thats the idea, I think I need a bit help with putting it in practice - hence why I asked.